# Excel row color from percentage of 100

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have a row (5 colums) that indicate 0 to 100 %
Like this that show 40% (green) and 80% (blue).
Is it possible to fill the 5 colums with a color, and show maybe 66%.
Row A, B, C and so on, have nothing to do with each other.

[image]

OPDATE
If looking at Sparklines, how can I then combine these two, into one ?
[image]

Comment: it's difficult with five rows, could be easier with just one. Since Excel 2010 you can use [sparklines](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-sparklines-to-show-data-trends-1474e169-008c-4783-926b-5c60e620f5ca)

Comment: Is there any reason that you are not just using a bar chart?

Comment: If you insist on making this using the cells in Excel though, which seems bizzarre, you cannot "half" fill a cell. So you are going to have to simply spread your graph over more rows.1 cell would be 2%, to get 66% you fill in 33 cells out of 50.

Comment: Hi Máté thx. i will try to look at that :-)
Panomosh Yes and No, and maybe it's because I haven't looked more into it, but I need some layout that need to match the row as showed, because I need some text and so on, over the colums for the A and B row.

Comment: "how can I then combine these two, into one ? " - if you need it so big, then just use a chart. There you can combine bar and line